# Concurrency test of UDP server

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp, load-testing

I need to write a script to stress test the UDP server.It needs to simulate about 5000 online users and about 400 concurrent users.I couldn't find a similar function on Google, so I wrote a UDP client myself.But I had a problem simulating multiple clients.The solution I came up with:

**One socket per client**

1. How to mark online users and concurrent users when using multithreading and multiple sockets to simulate clients?

   I encapsulate the client into classes,in this class __ init__ The method of adding one to a variable is used to record the of online users.In this way, concurrent operations cannot be performed successfully
2. Is it feasible to create 5000 sockets with threads? Is this a best practice? Good performance?

**Other approaches?**

Is there another approach I haven't thought of? Am I on the wrong track?

Is there a mature testing framework that can be used for reference?

Finally, English is not my mother tongue. Please forgive me for my typos or grammar.Thank you for your reading and look forward to your reply.

Comment: With UDP there isn't a whole lot of advantage to using more than one socket.  A single UDP socket can send and receive UDP packets to/from multiple locations without any problems.

Comment: OK, I'll try jemeter in another answer first. In the future, it can be realized by writing scripts by yourself. As you can see, I'm a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) tool which is free, open source and modular
2. There is [UDP Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-udp-the-ultimate-guide) sampler plugin which adds support of the UDP protocol to JMeter, see
3. The "5000 online users and 400 concurrent users" requirement may be interpreted in the following manner: real users don't hammer the system under test non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations, i.e. read text, type response, fill forms, take a phone call, etc. So you need to introduce realistic [think times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time) using JMeter [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) so you could come up with the configuration when:

   - 5000 users are "online" (connected to the server)
   - 4600 are not doing anything, just "sleeping"
   - 400 are actively sending requests
4. As long as your machine is capable of doing this without running out of CPU, RAM, Network, etc - it should be fine, personally I would use something like [greenlet](https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Sorry, I need to dynamically obtain the data returned by the server as the data sent to the server in the client heartbeat. The data returned by the server is serialized using protobuf. I need to deserialize the binary data and extract one of the fields to build a heartbeat package based on the data, so that the server can determine that there is a user link. How to use JMeter to realize this process?

Comment: It's possible to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting so you can serialize requests/deserialise responses. If you prefer Python if worth considering [Locust](https://locust.io/) tool so you could focus on your code and leave the concurrency, execution and reporting to Locust

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!Let me take a look at locust's documentation first.